# jQuery AJAX Post not writing JSON data to server file

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm new to this language stack...  Trying to understand why the .json file on the server isn't being populated with the data from the ajax post.  Below are two functions.  The first is a jquery function running on the browser, and the other is a php function called by the jquery that runs on the server.  The file permissions for the directory on the server are read-write, /var/www

There is currently a zero length file named post_Sched.json where the php function should write the json data.

```
<script>
    function theFunction() {
                   console.log("about to post to post_Sched.php")
        console.log("post_Sched_jstringed = " + post_Sched_jstringed);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "post_Sched.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'data': post_Sched_jstringed },
            //dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (response) {
                // response from php 
                $("#jresult").text(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
        console.log("just posted to post_Sched.php")
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>JSON Post Response: </h2>
        <div id="jresult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a php file called post_Sched.php

```
<?php
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  $file = fopen('post_Sched.json','w');
  fwrite($file, $data);
  fclose($file);
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

p.s. There is a global variable in the jquery function for the JSON data, and I can see the proper stringify'ed result, so I know the jsonDat is correct:

```
  var post_Sched_jstringed = JSON.stringify(Sched);
```

Developer tools console shows parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Can anyone explain the problem and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hopefully you don't have a DOM ready handler and console.logs in your PHP code?

Comment: yes, apparently I did.  I made an edit to the php here, to show the current state.  I also ran what's shown here and isn't working yet.

Comment: "By the way, I see the entire php function in the Object responseText (from developer tools in chrome).", so it returns the php function as if it's HTML? I don't know php, but it if I read that right it's not executing the code and I don't see the <?php> or how it goes, is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data: jsonDat,
```

with

```
data: {data: jsonDat},
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

```
<?php

//echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpinfo();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $json = $_POST['post_Sched_jstringed'];
    print_r($_POST);

    $file = fopen('post_Sched.json','w+');
    fwrite($file, json_encode($json)); // The object is automatically deserialized, so if you want it as json, it has to be serialized again
    fclose($file);

}

?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function theFunction() {
        console.log("about to post to post_Sched.php")

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "", // Take note the url was changed to same page, while I was working with this.
            //dataType: "json", // Removing this resolved the client-side error
            type: "post",
            data: { // I strongly recommend having data be an object with key-value pairs.
                post_Sched_jstringed: {
                    prop1: 232,
                    prop2: "asfasf"
                }
            },

            success: function (response) {
                // response from php
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
        console.log("just posted to post_Sched.php")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't do it.  I think I'm going to use a different server side scripting language - something other than PHP (probably python). I'm early in the development phase and it will be more familiar...

Comment: I made a few updates to the question to incorporate the current state of the problem.  Current problem state: JSON data not getting added to the post_Sched.json file, and there is a parser error being reported in the response from the POST

Comment: I installed PHP and experimented a little, dataType: "json" was causing the client error, changed the data to be an object with key and value, the reason it wasn't saving anything to the file was that the object wasn't serialized in the variable, it was sent serialized but it seems PHP deserialized it for you, to save it as json I've serialized it again. The comments in the example portrays the changes.

Comment: I was able to get the post and response back after removing  "dataType: "JSON"" and also using "data: { data: post_Sched_jstringed },"  however the response returned is the entire php file (rather than response from a line I've since inserted: "echo json_encode($json);", and the JSON text file isn't being updated in /var/www/ directory.  It appears the php file isn't being run, just returned.  I'd update my post to the current state, but assume that isn't the proper protocol, as it makes the Q and A transcript a moving target.

Comment: I updated my post to show the latest version of the code, and verified the php file has executable permission

Comment: Make sure the key in "$data = $_POST["post_Sched_jstringed"];" corresponds with the query sent to the server, in the example the parameter was "post_Sched_jsstringed", but you've changed it to "data" on the client, so it should be "$data = $_POST["data"];" on the server.

Comment: still not working, but done with this thread after being down-voted (apparently seen as not clearly thought out questions or sloppy descriptions).  I suspect this issue may be a configuration in the apache2 php settings may be needed....